# How can I split input using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a script in Linux, that takes input from user.

For example, this could be a line of input:

```
name = Ruba
```

I need to take the `"Ruba"` from the input, so how can i split the input and take the last part?

Comment: Which shell? bash, sh, csh, zsh, qzs, ksh, hash?

Comment: Ruby, Python, Lua, CoffeeScript?

Comment: If you take `Ruba` as input, what are you splitting on? What's the 'last part'?

Comment: The user enter the whole (name = Ruba) or (ID = 123)
so I need to take the last part of the string "Ruba" or "123"

Comment: You can read the input in one string and then split the string using space delimiter. Or do you want to read only last word of input at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IFS` in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html), which is the "internal field separator" and tells bash how to delimit words. You can read your input in with `IFS` set to a space (or whatever delimiter) and get an array back as input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Type in something: "

# read in input, using spaces as your delimiter.
# line will be an array
IFS=' ' read -ra line

# If your bash supports it, you can use negative indexing
# to get the last item
echo "last item is: ${line[-1]}"
```

Test run:

```
$ ./inscript.sh 
Type in something: 
name = ruba
last item is: ruba
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read name:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Name: " name
echo $name
```

The code above prompts for name and output it.

If your input is "name = Ruba"

```
#!/bin/bash
read name
name=$( echo $name | sed 's/.*=\ *//' )
echo $name
```

The code above read a line like "name = Ruba" and remove all characters preceding **=** and spaces after **=**.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
read input
echo $input |cut -d'=' -f2 | read name
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as it does not trim the whitespace.  This returns " Ruba" in the provided example, not "Ruba".

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read input
awk -F"= " '{print $2}' <<<"$input"
```